# Motherboard audio to analog (RCA red/white)

Tags: audio, motherboard, spdif

I'm building a NES PC casemod and want to use the RCA jacks in the case for the audio connection. I'm using the [Intel D945GCLF2](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d945gclf2/sb/e45013002us.pdf) which has motherboard pins for front-panel audio as well as S/PDIF audio.

What would you suggestion doing in this case? It seems to be easier to wire the front-panel audio pins to left/right RCA jacks but is it as simple as wiring the signal/ground or do I have to convert the audio signals from digital to analog?

Has anyone done any motherboard audio wiring who could shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motherboard PDF reference you link shows a **Audio header** reference on the last page.
These are for wiring to a cabinet speaker.

If you want to extend Stereo output over two RCA jacks,
I think connecting them internally to the **Front Panel header**
(integrated HD, numbered '**7**' on page 3)
over the **front-left** and **front-right** jacks would be suitable.
This can be done with an extension wire or manually wiring through the signal/ground paths.

You can change the HD Audio configuration to use Stereo output (rather than 5.1) later.

[**S/PDIF**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF) is usually a digital path.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it will be analogue audio, and the wiring would be simple. It's possible that there could be pins for S/PDIF on the motherboard, but I expect they would be labeled as such.

It's hard to say any more without knowing what motherboard it is.

Comment: I was thinking of testing the audio connections to see what I get. There is a link in my question to the motherboard's technical specification document. There are both front-panel and SPDIF pinks on the motherboard.